# Prove with potential method that dynamic table with $q > 1$ expansion runs in amortized constant time

Tags: runtime-analysis, arrays, amortized-analysis, dynamic-array

Suppose I have a dynamic table supporting $Insert$ procedure, which sets an input value after the tail of the dynamic table. If the underlying table is already full, we multiply its size by $q > 1$. (I have proof that that arrangement leads to amortized constant time for $Insert$: [see this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/76629/49711).)

My best attempt so far is: $\Phi_i = \alpha n_i + \beta N_i$, where $n_i$ is the number of elements in the dynamic table after the $i$th operation, and $N_i$  is the total capacity of the underlying array after the  $i$th operation.

The above leads to:

(1)
If there is more room for a new value, $n_i = n_{i - 1} + 1$, and $N_i = N_{i - 1}$:
\begin{aligned}
\hat{c_i} &= c_i + \Phi_i - \Phi_{i - 1} \\
          &= 1   + (\alpha n_i + \beta N_i) - (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \beta N_{i - 1}) \\
          &= 1   + (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \alpha + \beta N_{i - 1}) - (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \beta N_{i - 1}) \\
          &= 1 + \alpha \\
          &= \Theta(1).
\end{aligned}

(2) However, if there is no more room for the new value, we need to make the underlying array larger; in our case, we multiply its capacity by a constant $q > 1$:

Now, we have: $n_i = n_{i - 1} + 1$ and $N_i = qN_{i - 1}$:
\begin{aligned}
\hat{c}_i &= c_i + \Phi_i - \Phi_{i - 1} \\
          &= 1   + (\alpha n_i + \beta N_i) - (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \beta N_{i - 1}) \\
          &= 1 + (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \alpha + \beta qN_{i - 1}) - (\alpha n_{i - 1} + \beta N_{i - 1}) \\
          &= 1 + \alpha + (q - 1) \beta N_{i - 1}.
\end{aligned}
... and at this point, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you used $1$ as the non-amortized cost of a resizing.

Define $\Phi_i$ as $\frac{q^2}{q-1}$ times the number of elements inserted in the table since the last resizing. In formulas let $\Phi_i = \frac{q^2}{q-1} \cdot ( i - \frac{N_i}{q} ) = \frac{q^2}{q-1} i - \frac{q}{q-1} N_i$.

If the $i$-th element is inserted and no resizing happens then the worst-case cost of the operation is $1$ and $N_i = N_{i-1}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
1 + \Phi_i - \Phi_{i-1} &= 1 + \left(\frac{q^2}{q-1} i - \frac{q}{q-1} N_{i-1} \right) - \left( \frac{q^2}{q-1} (i-1) - \frac{q}{q-1} N_{i-1} \right) \\
&= 1+ \frac{q^2}{q-1}.
\end{align*}
$$

If the $i$-th element is inserted an a resizing happens then $N_i =  q N_{i-1}$ and the worst-case cost of the operation is $1 + N_i = 1 + q N_{i-1}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
1 + q N_{i-1} + \Phi_i - \Phi_{i-1} &= 
1 + q N_{i-1} + \left(\frac{q^2}{q-1} i - \frac{q^2}{q-1} N_{i-1} \right) - \left( \frac{q^2}{q-1}(i-1) - \frac{q}{q-1} N_{i-1} \right)\\
&= 1 + q N_{i-1} + \frac{q^2}{q-1} - (\frac{q^2}{q-1} - \frac{q}{q-1}) N_{i-1} \\
&= 1 + q N_{i-1} + \frac{q^2}{q-1} - q N_{i-1} \\
&= 1+ \frac{q^2}{q-1}.
\end{align*}
$$